# what's the best solution for privilege separation in Apache for content manager in PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, php-fpm, mod-proxy

I have several VirtualHost, and several web in the same VirtualHost:

- web1.example.org
- web2.example.org
- www.example.org/web3
- www.example.org/web4

I tried use mod_proxy, mod_proxy_fcgi + PHP-FPM:

Alias /myfoo /web/other/myfoo
  ProxyPassMatch ^/myfoo/(.*.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/web/other/myfoo/$1
  Alias /2myfoo /web/other/2myfoo
  ProxyPassMatch ^/2myfoo/(.*.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9002/web/other/2myfoo/$1

but this not read .htaccess files of my users.

If I use suEXEC, I don't set in:

- www.example.org/web3
- www.example.org/web4
- ...

because all they are in the same virtualhost.

The only solution is use container or diferents instances of httpd? or i can fix it (mod_proxy + php-fpm).

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what good alias doing for you there. And you don't need to specify $1 here,

`ProxyPassMatch   ^/myfoo/(.*\.php(/.*))?$   fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/web/other/myfoo/`
`ProxyPassMatch ^/2myfoo/(.*\.php(/.*))?$    fcgi://127.0.0.1:9002/web/other/2myfoo/`